# React native for loop getting index

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is probably a super simple question, but I have the following:

```
let groups = [{}, {}, {}];

for(let g of groups) {
    console.log(g);
}
```

How do I get the index number of said group? Preferably without doing a count.

Comment: I'm not sure about React, but in javascript there is ```for-in``` that goes through indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looping through groups, you could loop through groups.entries() which returns for each element, the index and the value.

Then you can extract those value with destructuring:

```
let groups = [{}, {}, {}];

for(let [i, g] of groups.entries()) {
    console.log(g);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively use `forEach()`:

```
groups.forEach((element, index) => {
    // do what you want
});
```

Comment: I get `.forEach() is not a function`

Comment: @bryan Do you have the same definition of `groups` as in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Simply,

```
let groups = [{}, {}, {}];

for(let g of groups) {
    console.log(groups.indexOf(g));
}
```